# Trying to install .CAP, getting error SW 64 00

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

Hi I am trying to load a .CAP file onto a GlobalPlatform card, I am getting the following error. How can I debug this?

[image]

Comment: Always use text instead of pictures. Google cannot inspect pictures as well as text. Other users having the same problem will not be able to find answers then.

Answer (score 0):

`6400` is a generic error. You will have to ask the vendor / manufacturer for more information.

> 64XX: Execution error, the state of persistent memory is unchanged.

Where XX=00 means no information given.

---

In general, try a smaller block size (FF is a bit much command data) and make sure that the Java Card version matches that of the card.